# Android Viewpager onclick fires on next page

Tags: java, android, android-viewpager

I have a viewPager that slides between views in my app but when an onclick listener is fired it sometimes updates the next page for some strange reason.

```
public class GoalsPagerAdapter extends android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter {


    int position;
    EditText goalTitle,goalDesc,goalReading,visTime;
    User user = MainActivity.getSingleton();
    FloatingActionButton saveChangesButton;
    Goal g;
    DBHandler db;
    Switch aSwitch;
    boolean saveChanges;
    Hashtable fonts;
    Context context;
    String goalImageUri;
    LayoutInflater inflater;
    TextView goalNameLabel,goalDescLabel,visLengthLabel,visReadingLabel;
    ImageView goalImage;
    byte[] imageBytes;
    Button saveChangesDetailedButton,discardChangesDetailedButton;


    public GoalsPagerAdapter(Context context,int position){
        this.position =position;
        this.context =context;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return user.getGoals().size();
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
         container.removeView((LinearLayout) object);
    }



    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(final ViewGroup container, final int position) {


        inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.detailed_goal_layout,null);
        goalNameLabel = (TextView) container.findViewById(R.id.goalNameLabel);

        saveChanges=false;



        db = new DBHandler(context);
        g = user.getGoals().get(position);
        fonts = user.getFonts();

        goalImage = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.goalImageView);
        if(g.getGoalImage()!=null){
            byte[] image = user.getGoals().get(position).getGoalImage();
            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(image,0,image.length);
            goalImage.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        }
        goalTitle = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.goalTitleEditText);
        goalDesc = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.goalDescriptionEditText);
        goalReading = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.goalVisReadingEditText);
        visTime = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.visTimeEditText);
        saveChangesDetailedButton = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.saveChangesDetailedButton);
        discardChangesDetailedButton = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.discardChangesDetailedButton);
        saveChangesDetailedButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        discardChangesDetailedButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

        aSwitch = (Switch) view.findViewById(R.id.switch3);
        aSwitch.setChecked(g.getSwitchState());

        visLengthLabel = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.visLengthLabel);
        visLengthLabel.setTypeface((Typeface) fonts.get("Socialize"));
        visReadingLabel = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.visReadingLabel);
        visReadingLabel.setTypeface((Typeface) fonts.get("Socialize"));
        goalNameLabel = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.goalNameLabel);
        goalNameLabel.setTypeface((Typeface) fonts.get("Socialize"));
        goalDescLabel = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.goalDescLabel);
        goalDescLabel.setTypeface((Typeface) fonts.get("Socialize"));


        final Drawable originalDrawable = visTime.getBackground();
        visTime.setClickable(false);
        visTime.setFocusable(false);
        visTime.setBackground(null);
        visTime.setTypeface((Typeface) fonts.get("Socialize_Circle"));

        goalDesc.setClickable(false);
        goalDesc.setFocusable(false);
        goalDesc.setTypeface((Typeface) fonts.get("Socialize_Circle"));
        goalDesc.setBackground(null);

        goalTitle.setClickable(false);
        goalTitle.setFocusable(false);
        goalTitle.setTypeface((Typeface) fonts.get("Socialize"));
        goalTitle.setBackground(null);

        goalReading.setClickable(false);
        goalReading.setFocusable(false);
        goalReading.setTypeface((Typeface) fonts.get("Socialize_Circle"));
        goalReading.setBackground(null);


        //set position
        //position =

        goalTitle.setText(user.getGoals().get(position).getName());
        goalDesc.setText(user.getGoals().get(position).getDescription());
        goalReading.setText(user.getGoals().get(position).getVisReader());

        aSwitch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                if(isChecked){
                    String temp = "true";
                    db.updateGoalSwitchState(g,temp);
                    user.getGoals().get(position).setSwitchState(true);

                }
                else{
                    String temp = "false";
                    db.updateGoalSwitchState(g,temp);
                    user.getGoals().get(position).setSwitchState(false);
                }

            }
        });

        saveChangesButton = (FloatingActionButton) view.findViewById(R.id.saveChangesButton);
        saveChangesButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (!saveChanges) {
                    visTime.setClickable(true);
                    visTime.setFocusable(true);
                    visTime.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
                    visTime.setBackgroundResource(android.R.drawable.edit_text);

                    saveChangesButton.setBackgroundResource(android.R.drawable.ic_menu_add);
                    goalDesc.setClickable(true);
                    goalDesc.setFocusable(true);
                    goalDesc.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
                    goalDesc.setBackgroundResource(android.R.drawable.edit_text);

                    goalTitle.setClickable(true);
                    goalTitle.setFocusable(true);
                    goalTitle.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
                    goalTitle.setBackgroundResource(android.R.drawable.edit_text);

                    goalReading.setClickable(true);
                    goalReading.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
                    goalReading.setFocusable(true);
                    goalReading.setBackgroundResource(android.R.drawable.edit_text);
                    saveChanges=true;

//                    goalImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
//                        @Override
//                        public void onClick(View v) {
//                            Intent photoPickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
//                            photoPickerIntent.setType("image/*");
//                            startActivityForResult(photoPickerIntent,1);
//                        }
//                    });

                    saveChangesDetailedButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    saveChangesDetailedButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            String newGoalTitle, newGoalDesc, newVisReading;
                            int newGoalVisTime;
                            newGoalTitle = goalTitle.getText().toString();
                            newGoalDesc = goalDesc.getText().toString();

                            newVisReading = goalReading.getText().toString().trim();
                            newGoalVisTime = Integer.parseInt(visTime.getText().toString());


                            Goal g = user.getGoals().get(position);
                            if (!g.getName().equals(newGoalTitle) || !g.getDescription().equals(newGoalDesc) || g.getVisTime() != newGoalVisTime || newVisReading !=g.getVisReader() ) {
                                Goal newGoal = new Goal(newGoalTitle, newGoalDesc, "12/12/12", newGoalVisTime, true, newVisReading);
                                if(imageBytes!=null){
                                    newGoal.setGoalImage(imageBytes);
                                }
                                newGoal.setGoalImage(g.getGoalImage());
                                user.getGoals().set(position,newGoal);
                                db.updateGoalData(newGoal, g.getName());

                                Toast.makeText(context, "Goal updated successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            } else {
                                Toast.makeText(context, "No changes were made", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                            saveChanges=false;
                            discardChangesDetailedButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                            saveChangesDetailedButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                            setUnClickable();
                        }
                    });
                    discardChangesDetailedButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    discardChangesDetailedButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            goalTitle.setText(g.getName());
                            goalDesc.setText(g.getDescription());
                            goalReading.setText(g.getVisReader());
                            visTime.setText(g.getVisTime()+"");
                            setUnClickable();
                            saveChanges=false;
                            discardChangesDetailedButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                            saveChangesDetailedButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                        }
                    });

                } else {
                    saveChanges=false;

                    saveChangesDetailedButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    discardChangesDetailedButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    setUnClickable();



                }
            }
        });


        container.addView(view);

        return view;

    }



    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
        return view == object;
    }



    public void setUnClickable(){
        visTime.setClickable(false);
        visTime.setFocusable(false);
        visTime.setBackgroundResource(0);


        goalDesc.setClickable(false);
        goalDesc.setFocusable(false);
        goalDesc.setBackgroundResource(0);

        goalTitle.setClickable(false);
        goalTitle.setFocusable(false);
        goalTitle.setBackgroundResource(0);

        goalReading.setClickable(false);
        goalReading.setFocusable(false);
        goalReading.setBackgroundResource(0);

        saveChangesButton.setBackgroundResource(android.R.drawable.ic_menu_edit);
        goalImage.setOnClickListener(null);
    }


}
```

this is my ViewPager class:

```
public class GoalsViewPagerActivity extends Activity {
    int pos;
    ViewPager viewPager;
    GoalsPagerAdapter gpa;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.goals_view_pager_layout);

        Intent prevIntetn = getIntent();
        pos = prevIntetn.getIntExtra("position", 0);

        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.goalsViewPager);
        gpa = new GoalsPagerAdapter(this, pos);
        viewPager.setAdapter(gpa);
        viewPager.setCurrentItem(pos);
    }


}
```

Please let me know if you guys see the error in my code.
Appreciate any help in advance :)